# Is it possible to object Ids from unfocused console tabs?

Tags: javascript, tab, console

I know it is possible to get object ids from focused primary and subtabs, but it is possible for me to use the Ids returned from getPrimaryTabIds, parse through and use those ids to somehow return the objectIds of those tabs?

If so, please explain how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the objectId from getPageInfo() which returns a JSON string that you can parse.

Will update with full solution once finished as the question was upvoted.*

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getpageinfo.htm